# Why is the array concatenating the numbers -vs- adding them as I would like

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have tried several methods and am not understanding why I cant simple get the sum of the numbers in my array. I.E.

```
Logger.log(shirtColor)
Logger.log(shirtColor.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
```

Logger shows:

```
Info    [0.0, 1, 2, 1]
Info    0121
```

Comment: Most likely because they are ***strings***,

Comment: Try `Logger.log(shirtColor.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b, 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `shirtColor` array contains string elements. That's the reason it is appending as a string.

If `shirtColor` is an array of string elements.

```js
const arr = ['1', '2', '1'];

const res = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(res); // 0121
```

If `shirtColor` contains numeric elements.

```js
const arr = [0.0, 1, 2, 1];

const res = arr.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b, 0);

console.log(res); // 4
```

To achieve the requirement, You can convert a string to a number in JavaScript using the unary plus operator (+).

```js
const arr = ['0.0', '1', '2', '1'];

const res = arr.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b, 0);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the comments to understand my oversight. I was pushing data that was a string. Instead the data I was pushing I added Number()

```
if (vs[i][15] > 0) {
            shirtColor.push(Number(vs[i][15]))}
```

Comment: You should change it to numbers at it's source - the spreadsheet.

Comment: Ahh, is that how you can fix that assign the cell to a number! Thanks you!!